# Is there some way to compress CSS and Javascript only for certain users?

Tags: 7

When I check the source of my web pages I am appalled at the amount of Javascript links in the page, but I have disabled the CSS and JS compression as I am often in development mode.

Is there some way to disable the compression for admins and developers and enable it only for viewers?

Comment: This may not be the feedback you're looking for, but does "as I am often in development mode" mean that you develop on the production server? This is just one of many good reasons to set up a separate (local) development server.

Comment: It is for a personal blog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg/). If the user has the correct permissons you can add ?advagg=-1 to the URL and all CSS/JS files are un-aggregated for that page request. You can also set a cookie on the `admin/config/development/performance/advagg/operations` page so you no longer need to add that to every URL.

Comment: I have a new question concerning beautifying the html generated by drupal - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239888 - and I think your knowledge of page generation might help. Thanks