# Where in the page generation pipeline can an HTML beautifier be placed?

Tags: 7

I need to view the HTML generated by Drupal and it is pretty hard. If I want to the final output to be put through an HTML beautifier before sending it off to the client where would I do that?

I am sure some of the page optimization utilities on the `admin/config/development/performance` or the `advagg` module are at the right place in the pipeline. What stage or APIs would I have to hook into to accomplish something this?

Are there any APIs which can be hooked into to accomplish this or even modules to this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in advagg is a good example, you have to get the response content with `$response->getContent()` in a response subscriber http://cgit.drupalcode.org/advagg/tree/src/EventSubscriber/ResponseSubscriber.php?h=8.x-3.x

```
  public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    // Only care about HTML responses.
    if (stripos($event->getResponse()->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'text/html') === FALSE) {
      return;
    }

    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $html_markup = $response->getContent();
    // modify html markup
    $response->setContent($html_markup);
  }
```

Comment: What is the appropriate stage in Drupal 7?

Comment: I see you've added a new tag for D7, don't know anything about this, but you can try to look in the D7 code of advagg